# Flutter- Add Google Calendar directly into my app

Tags: flutter, calendar, google-calendar-api, flutter-dependencies

just like when you add a widget of google calendar on the homescreen it tells you the tasks you have for that day according to the current time and it allows you to get a day/week/month wise view, is there a way to have such widget type thing directly into my flutter app and not using device_calender flutter_native_calendar and all that
Plain google calendar directly into my app

i've tried device_calendar , manage calendar, flutter native calendar but what exactly im looking for is to directly show the events for that day, week, month as you would see in a home screen widget of your google calendar and do additin, deletion of events

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Google Calendar API** for Get, Delete, Create events and many other things.
First you need to configure/create  new project on  Google APIs dashboard https://console.developers.google.com/
and then using [syncfusion_flutter_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) or [google_meet_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/google_meet_sdk) package you can sync google calender into flutter app.

There are tons of articls and documentations available which can help you to integrate google calender in flutter app.

For your reference attaching few resources here:

Google Calendar API : https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview

Here is very nice article on how to get google calender events in flutter app :  https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/11300/how-to-load-the-google-calendar-events-to-the-flutter-calendar-sfcalendar-in-ios